# Joint PDF cross sectional area - what does it represent?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given the PDF of a continuous joint distribution:$$f(x,y)$$ Why isn't it true that taking a cross sectional area of the distribution parallel to the y axis represents the following:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dy = P(X=x)$$

Surely integrating for all possible values of y with respect to y, is akin to summing all probabilities P(x, y), where x is fixed at a given value. If that is the case, that would be calculating the probability that the random variable X is equal to a given value x, as you have exhausted all instances where X = x. Why is it that the cross sectional area *still* yields a probability density as opposed to an absolute probability?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!
What you are looking for is precisely the marginal distribution, please, check the following (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution)

Comment: @Arteom Thank you for the link! On the wiki page, it states that for continuous random variables, integrating over y gives the marginal PDF of x. I'm still confused as to why the result is still a density function. If my understanding is correct you are essentially summing the products of all infinitesimal intervals of y by their respective probability densities. Doesn't that yield an "absolute" probability in the same way that it does for a PDF where there is only one random variable?

Comment: In short, because $P(X=x)=0$.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain why infinitesimal interval * probability density = probability density. Why doesn't a cross section represent a probability in the same way that an area under a PDF of one random variable does when the axis in both cases represent the same things? Obviously I'm overlooking something but I can't tell what.